# i want to make 2 words connected. so far only manage 1 word at a time

Tags: python

I am making an AI system that will reply when given input. This happen because the question given has the words that the system wants. My problem is, how can I get two words combined to be detected? So far I only managed to get one word.

```
input_ls = user_input.split(" ")
processor = {
    "buy":False,
    "sell":False,
    "store":[],
    "general":False,
    "dict":False,
    "dict_lookup":[]
}

for w in input_ls:
    w = w.lower() # force capital letter into small letter
    if w in ["buy", "get", "ok"]:
        processor["buy"] = True
```

Comment: Give some example where your code fails and what you wanted the code to do

Comment: when you say two words, does it mean any two words from processor dictionary or you have predefined set of two words and both needs to be present in order for AI system to return that answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply count the number of words present in the string with `sum`:

```
>>> text = "buy this product"
>>> sum(1 for w in ["buy", "get", "ok"] if w in text)
1
>>> text = "buy this product. ok"
>>> sum(1 for w in ["buy", "get", "ok"] if w in text)
2
```

And check if the count is greater than or equal to 2:

```
>>> sum(1 for w in ["buy", "get", "ok"] if w in text) >= 2
True
```

Another, more efficient alternative would be to calculate the intersection of two sets. The desired words and the words in your sentence:

```
>>> set(text.lower().split())
{'buy', 'ok', 'product.', 'this'}
>>> set(text.lower().split()) & set(["buy", "get", "ok"])
{'buy', 'ok'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a list intersection between input_ls and list of words to detect 
and then iterate intersected list to set processor's values.

```
input_ls = user_input.split(" ")
processor = {
   ...
}

to_detect = ["buy", "get", "ok"]
intersect = list(set(input_ls) & set(to_detect))
for key in intersect:
    processor[key] = True
```

Dont forget to solve capitals, etc.. eg. by iterating input in advance and setting values to lower() or maybe using lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on solution ...

1. Group logical words into tuple in a dictionary so that it easy to identify the answers to be given by A.I. system when those words occur in sentence.
2. 2 dictionary should be created. `processor` dictionary with relevant pair of words and `processorAnswers` with answer that's related to those words.
3. Strip the given sentence of punctuation (e.g. `comma`, etc; you can have a method that strips all possible punctuation from input string), lower case it and split it with spaces
4. Iterate through the `processor` dictionary and mark the occurrence of the words in a tuple form. Counting Multiple occurrences of words can be ignored, like I did (optional).
5. Finally find the pair of words which have occurred in the sentence and display the relevant answer to those words from `processorAnswers` dictionary.

***NOTE:*** If more than one pair of words occur in sentence then in order to resolve which answer should be returned to the user, we should incorporate the counting of multiple occurrences of the words and return the tuple that has max hits on words (basically sum of occurrences in tuple).

---

```
user_input = input("What is your question?")
input_ls = user_input.replace(",", "").lower().split(" ")
processor = {
    ("buy", "sell"):(0,0),
    ("general", "dict"):(0,0)
}
processorAnswers = {
    ("buy", "sell"):"Welcome to buy and sell",
    ("general", "dict"):"This is general dictionary"
}
for pairs in processor.keys():
    if processor[pairs] != (1,1):
        if pairs[0] in input_ls and list(processor[pairs])[0] != 1:
            listTuple = list(processor[pairs])
            listTuple[0] = 1
            processor[pairs] = tuple(listTuple)
        if pairs[1] in input_ls and list(processor[pairs])[1] != 1:
            listTuple = list(processor[pairs])
            listTuple[1] = 1
            processor[pairs] = tuple(listTuple)

print(processor)

print("Answer is: ")
for pairs in processor.keys():
    if processor[pairs] == (1,1):
        print(processorAnswers[pairs])
```

Sample Run

```
========== RESTART: C:/loop.py ==========
What is your question?why buy sell sell buy sell buy general gene
{('buy', 'sell'): (1, 1), ('general', 'dict'): (1, 0)}
Answer is: 
Welcome to buy and sell
```

More than one answers possible scenario:

***NOTE:*** You can get as fancy as you want in resolving the tie.

```
user_input = input("What is your question?")
input_ls = user_input.replace(",", "").lower().split(" ")
processor = {
    ("buy", "sell"):(0,0),
    ("general", "dict"):(0,0)
}

processorAnswers = {
    ("buy", "sell"):"Welcome to buy and sell",
    ("general", "dict"):"This is general dictionary"
}

for pairs in processor.keys():
        if pairs[0] in input_ls:
            listTuple = list(processor[pairs])
            listTuple[0] = input_ls.count(pairs[0])
            processor[pairs] = tuple(listTuple)
        if pairs[1] in input_ls:
            listTuple = list(processor[pairs])
            listTuple[1] = input_ls.count(pairs[1])
            processor[pairs] = tuple(listTuple)

print(processor)

maxHits = 0
maxHitTuple = ()
for pairs in processor.keys():
    listTuple = list(processor[pairs])
    if (listTuple[0] > 0 and listTuple[1] > 0 and ((listTuple[0] + listTuple[1]) > maxHits)):
        maxHits = listTuple[0] + listTuple[1]
        maxHitTuple = pairs

print("Best Answer is: " + processorAnswers[maxHitTuple])
```

Sample Run:

```
What is your question?why buy sell buy sell general general general general general general
{('buy', 'sell'): (2, 2), ('general', 'dict'): (6, 0)}
Best Answer is: Welcome to buy and sell
```

Comment: tq sir. really appreciate your help

Comment: No problem, if my answer has resolved your problem or provided you pointers then please accept the answer and vote up :)